# Get the average difference between two values in time period

Tags: sql, postgresql

What I have:
A single table with ids and prices for date and time.

What I want to do:
To get the average difference of price for every id between the first and 15 minute of every day.
Conditions: I also want to use the last available price in 15 minutes if the 15 is missing. For example if 15 is missing, use the price in 14 minutes.

What I did:
My first step was to get the price after 15 minutes of every day for every id.

My code (I did a lot of tests with it, sorry if it doesn't look good and optimised enough) to get the last price(but not last available) in the 15 minutes interval:

```
WITH s as (
  SELECT DATE(date_value) as dt, date_value, stock_id sid, open FROM stocks_1min
)

SELECT sid, dt, date_value, s.open as second_price
FROM s

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT q.stock_id, DATE(q.date_value) as dat
    FROM stocks_1min q
    GROUP BY q.stock_id, dat
    ORDER BY q.stock_id ASC
  ) as end_price
           ON s.sid = end_price.stock_id 
    AND s.date_value = (SELECT date_value FROM s WHERE s.sid = end_price.stock_id AND s.dt = end_price.dat LIMIT 1) + interval '15 minutes'    

ORDER BY sid, dt;
```

What I didn't do:

- get the last AVAILABLE price in that interval.
- get the first price in that interval and use it in the same query with the last price in the interval
- If I got both prices then I can use AVG and Group By to get the needed value.

Expected result (example):
Table:

```
|stock_id|open(price)|date_value      |
|1       |10         |01-12-2020 09:31|
|1       |12         |01-12-2020 09:46|
|1       |14         |02-12-2020 09:31|
|1       |20         |02-12-2020 09:46|
|2       |14         |01-12-2020 09:31|
|2       |16         |01-12-2020 09:46|
|2       |2          |02-12-2020 09:31|
|2       |16         |02-12-2020 09:46|
```

Result:

```
|stock_id|average_difference|
| 1      | 4                | ((12-10) + (20-14)) / 2 = 4
| 2      | 8                | ((16-14) + (16-2)) / 2 = 8
```

I have never used "Partition By", but maybe here is the place to start with it?
It's my own project, where I want to test some statistical ideas for the stock market.
Thanks in advance!

You can use this link where it's a sample for testing: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/83597/1

Comment: The examples and data are great. Thanks for including those. The description is a little hard to follow. Are you saying you always want a single value per stock_id which is the mean of the difference encountered during the first 15 trading minutes of each day? In which case, any data after 09:45:59 can be ignored?

Comment: So you want to start by fetching the first price for each ID each day and the latest price which is not more than 15 minutes later? If the 2nd price is 16 minutes later we will return the 1st price twice?

Comment: @FlexYourData, Yes, my idea is to ignore all data for every day of the stock_id after the 15th minute. In the given example the average_difference is AVG(price15 - price1 for every date of the stock_id). where price15 is the price of the 15th minute and price1 is the price of 1st minute after the market is opened. So we get the difference for the first stock_id for all days and calculate the mean value, then for second stock_id, etc. Check how I calculated the average_difference in the Example result.

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin, look also the day, not only the time ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, you want to:

1. List the prices of each stock from each day during the first 15 minutes of the day
2. Identify the first and last (as defined by date_value) of the prices listed in step 1
3. Calculate the difference between the prices identified in step 2, by stock and day
4. Calculate the average of the differences calculated in step 3, by stock

If I have interpreted your question correctly, then:

```
WITH dat
AS
(
SELECT stock_id
      ,date_value::date AS date_of_date_value
      ,date_value
      ,MIN(date_value) OVER (PARTITION BY stock_id, date_value::date) AS min_date_value
      ,MAX(date_value) OVER (PARTITION BY stock_id, date_value::date) AS max_date_value
      ,"open" AS open_price
FROM stocks_1min
WHERE date_value::time <= '09:45:00.000'
),
dat2
AS
(
SELECT stock_id
      ,date_of_date_value
      ,AVG(CASE WHEN min_date_value = date_value THEN open_price ELSE NULL END) AS open_price_from
      ,AVG(CASE WHEN max_date_value = date_value THEN open_price ELSE NULL END) AS open_price_to
      ,AVG(CASE WHEN max_date_value = date_value THEN open_price ELSE NULL END) 
           - AVG(CASE WHEN min_date_value = date_value THEN open_price ELSE NULL END) AS open_price_diff
FROM dat
WHERE date_value = min_date_value OR date_value = max_date_value
GROUP BY stock_id
        ,date_of_date_value
)
SELECT stock_id, AVG(open_price_diff) AS avg_open_price_diff
FROM dat2
GROUP BY stock_id;
```

You may find that you need to wrap the calculation of open_price_diff with `ABS`, but I have not done that in the example above.

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/83597/12)

Comment: I'm really impressed! Thank you for this solution. You did it so quick and clear. It returns the mean value only for the first stocks_id and the difference for the others, but it's a good starting point for me. Thank you!

Comment: I think it returns the mean of differences across all days for all three stocks. You only have one day of data for stocks 2 and 3 so the mean difference is equal to the difference on the first (and only) day. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/30378e/1

Comment: Yes, your query was correct(the average of 1 row is the same value), the problem was in the number of dates per id inside the sample. I'm selecting your solution as accepted, because it is the fastest and also looks professional and clean. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I continued with the idea from your SQL and tried to get the solution without analytical function which you can if you want to.

**SQL**: ([dbfiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=60ff927ac910dd474ecacd435955fc96))

```
WITH 
day_min_time AS
(
         SELECT   Min(date_value)  min_time,
                  Date(date_value) dt,
                  stock_id
         FROM     stock_1min
         GROUP BY Date(date_value),
                  stock_id ), 
day_max_time AS
(
         SELECT   Max(sd.date_value)  max_time ,
                  Date(sd.date_value) dt,
                  sd.stock_id
         FROM     stock_1min sd
         JOIN     day_min_time dmt
         ON       sd.stock_id = dmt.stock_id
         AND      Date(sd.date_value) = dmt.dt
         WHERE    sd.date_value <= dmt.min_time + interval '15 minutes'
         GROUP BY date(sd.date_value) ,
                  sd.stock_id )
SELECT   round(avg(price_difference)) average_difference,
         stock_id
FROM     (
                    SELECT     max(sd.OPEN)-min(sd.OPEN) price_difference,
                               sd.stock_id ,
                               date(sd.date_value)
                    FROM       stock_1min sd
                    INNER JOIN day_min_time min_dmt
                    ON         min_dmt.stock_id = sd.stock_id
                    AND        date(sd.date_value) = min_dmt.dt
                    INNER JOIN day_max_time max_dmt
                    ON         max_dmt.stock_id = sd.stock_id
                    AND        date(sd.date_value) = max_dmt.dt
                    WHERE      sd.date_value BETWEEN min_dmt.min_time AND        max_dmt.max_time
                    GROUP BY   sd.stock_id ,
                               date(sd.date_value) ) final_inline_view
GROUP BY stock_id;
```

Here are the steps:

**Step 1**: Minimum recorded time for each day.

```
with day_min_time
as
(
 SELECT Min(date_value)  min_time,
       Date(date_value) dt,
       stock_id
FROM   stock_1min
GROUP  BY Date(date_value),
          stock_id 
)
```

**Step 2**: Maximum recorded time for each day which is 15 minutes from minimum recorded time for the day.It is using the CTE from step 1.

```
with day_max_time
 as
(
 SELECT   Max(sd.date_value)  max_time ,
         Date(sd.date_value) dt,
         sd.stock_id
FROM     stock_1min sd
JOIN     day_min_time dmt
ON       sd.stock_id = dmt.stock_id
AND      Date(sd.date_value) = dmt.dt
WHERE    sd.date_value <= dmt.min_time + interval '15 minutes'
GROUP BY date(sd.date_value) ,
         sd.stock_id)
```

**Step 3**: Use the time boundaries obtained from Step 1 and Step 2 to get the maximum  and minimum prices.

```
SELECT Max(sd.open) - Min(sd.open) price_difference,
       sd.stock_id,
       DATE(sd.date_value)
FROM   stock_1min sd
       INNER JOIN day_min_time min_dmt
               ON min_dmt.stock_id = sd.stock_id
                  AND DATE(sd.date_value) = min_dmt.dt
       INNER JOIN day_max_time max_dmt
               ON max_dmt.stock_id = sd.stock_id
                  AND DATE(sd.date_value) = max_dmt.dt
WHERE  sd.date_value BETWEEN min_dmt.min_time AND max_dmt.max_time
GROUP  BY sd.stock_id,
          DATE(sd.date_value)
```

**Step 4**: Get the average difference using the result from step 3:

```
SELECT Round(Avg(difference)) average_difference,
       stock_id
FROM   (SELECT Max(sd.open) - Min(sd.open) price_difference,
               sd.stock_id,
               DATE(sd.date_value)
        FROM   stock_1min sd
               INNER JOIN day_min_time min_dmt
                       ON min_dmt.stock_id = sd.stock_id
                          AND DATE(sd.date_value) = min_dmt.dt
               INNER JOIN day_max_time max_dmt
                       ON max_dmt.stock_id = sd.stock_id
                          AND DATE(sd.date_value) = max_dmt.dt
        WHERE  sd.date_value BETWEEN min_dmt.min_time AND max_dmt.max_time
        GROUP  BY sd.stock_id,
                  DATE(sd.date_value)) final_inline_view
GROUP  BY stock_id;
```